# Knit table with kableExtra package not showing desired output format

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I am trying to knit a table as html ouput in Rmarkdown. When I run the print table chunk in RStudio, I do get the desired output format in the Viewer tab:

However, when I try to knit the whole code to html, the table appears to lose its format in the html document:

[Table of html output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lox6L.png)

The code I use to render these html output:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```



```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
#run study
library(knitr)
library(broom)
library(kableExtra)
source("Load Base.R")

```

## FX Performance


```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}

source("functions/functions.R")

temp<-cria_table(df=df.xts.rets, datas = c("2019-10-21","2019-10-01","2019-01-04", "2018-10-25"), row.tablenames = c("WtD", "MtD", "YtD", "12M"),caption="FX Performance as deviation (in %) to benchmark")

kable(temp[-1,],digits = 1,caption = "FX Performance as deviation (in %) to benchmark") %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"))
```
````

the temp data frame is a simple data frame:

```
x<-sample(0:10, 13, replace = T)
y<-sample(0:10, 13, replace = T)
z<-sample(0:10, 13, replace = T)

temp2<-data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))
temp2<-t(temp2)
temp2<-as.data.frame(temp2)
rownames(temp2)<-c("MtD", "YtD", "12M")
names(temp2)<-c("BRL", "MXN", "COP", "PEN", "CLP", "TRY", "ZAR", "RUB", "IDR", "INR", "SGD", "CNH", 
"KRW")
```

temp structure:

```
dput(temp)
structure(c(NA, 0.245944762916706, -0.894156351362008, 3.08653725521899, 
NA, 0.498928791459474, 2.18942517241514, 5.89628231017694, NA, 
0.65225368445716, -3.92645080384256, -6.16331871130317, NA, 0.121208248520244, 
0.735245304879228, -0.403569989918617, NA, 0.0319232052804264, 
1.19548773782774, 0.418607196177323, NA, 1.17741658565871, 3.09916586536103, 
5.1411087783602, NA, 0.29199277703813, -4.26010006701491, -6.85199909276568, 
NA, -0.446468482414186, 0.0407432119243767, -2.48418064300502, 
NA, -1.14967013429852, 2.14931978994899, 1.63392653902903, NA, 
-1.00935707767996, 2.42923572611407, 4.17436117595411, NA, -0.550796158031552, 
-0.22678585243624, -0.913622930913149, NA, -0.715336967669677, 
0.351449936516834, -0.544645694784129, NA, -0.4431607587566, 
-1.17144079153269, -1.13960550555942), .Dim = c(4L, 13L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("WtD", "MtD", "YtD", "12M"), c("BRL", "MXN", "COP", "PEN", 
    "CLP", "TRY", "ZAR", "RUB", "IDR", "INR", "SGD", "CNH", "KRW"
    )))
```

Comment: Well by using your R Markdown code and the ``temp`` data code you provided it seems to work just fine. Kable seems to do the job. https://i.imgur.com/lSIVSQc.png

Comment: What ``R version`` do you have and what about ``kableExtra`` ?

Comment: I am using kableExtra when I use the kable_styling function after the pipe in the kable call.

Comment: > sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Comment: Yes I know you are using ``kableExtra`` and ``Knitr``. I'm not sure where is the problem then since 3.4.3 shouldn't cause any problem with kable as far as I know. I know that if you were to use the table/html with something such as ``blogdown`` you would maybe need to change some css code to display it properly.

Comment: Could you simpy try to add : ``kable(x, format = "html", ...)`` ? You don't specify the format in your code.

Comment: tried...still giving the same results :(

Maybe is some Rmarkdown configuration I have in my RStudio?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe. Can you post the dput of your real ``temp`` if possible? ``dput(temp)``. This way we'll know your code is not the problem

Comment: I edite it in the post, couldnt post here because it was too long!

Comment: Thank you. Your code is still working on my pc, I'm not sure what the problem could be, maybe you could try to update your ``R Version``. I'll post something as an answer, can you try it please? I'll delete it after.

Comment: Can anyone help me here? Stil couldnt figure that out!